# Open ASP.NET GridView item in new page or tab - how to?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a simple ASP.NET GridView......... Using ASP.NET 2.0.
For some reason you cant right click on a item in a grieview and say Open in NEW tab or page. Why is that? And how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of ASP.NET works by posting back using javascript, rather than links. I guess gridview buttons work this way. If you want to be able to right-click/New tab you will have to add a hyperlink or HTML anchor to the gridview, and supply it with the appropriate URL - you'll need to generate some way of passing the row data to the url too, such as QueryString values identifying the row.